# What is the difference betwee submitForm, handleSubmit, onSubmit in formik?

Tags: formik

Formik doc says

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/form-submission

> To submit a form in Formik, you need to somehow fire off the provided
>   handleSubmit(e) or submitForm prop. When you call either of these
>   methods, Formik will execute the following (pseudo code) each time:
>
> ```
> ----
> Run all field-level validations, validate, and validationSchema asynchronously and deeply merge results
> ---
> ```

I cannot understand the form submission process. What is the difference between handleSubmit, onSubmit, submitForm.

Does validations always run asynchronously even if I provide a synchronous validate function?

Which of the above three function run asynchronously?
What do they return?

Comment: > **handleSubmit can be passed as is to a form's onSubmit event andpreventDefault. submitForm cannot.**

Answer (score 9):

`onSubmit` - it's native event prop of `form` component. It's do not have relation to your question

---

I haven't use Formik. But if we take a look on their code:  https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/packages/formik/src/Formik.tsx#L740

`submitForm` - more low level function, that return Promise, and you could work with result afterwards. 
`handleSubmit` - inside invoke `submitForm`, and handle all error if occurs  inside, return nothing. (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/packages/formik/src/Formik.tsx#L833)

Both of this function is async, because they wrapped with `useEventCallback`.

By default validation always will come after you trigger any of the events `submitForm` or `handleSubmit`. What type of validation sync or async you could write by yourself depend on this first `validate` example (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/docs/guides/validation.md#validate)

There is list of methods when validation is run, or how you could trigger it:
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/26c4f8627a5ecfd81ec2196c7a9687b3f39f2836/docs/guides/validation.md#validate

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1027

"HandleSubmit can be passed as is to a form's onSubmit event and preventDefault. submitForm cannot."