# How to pass Formik form values via an intermediate function to the handleSubmit event?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Ok, so far I have successfully used the handleSubmit() and could manage to access the updated (user edited) form values but what if you want to have a messagebox prompt user to Save\Discard changes and when user selects the Save button on the messagebox, you want the form's handleSubmit() even gets called and you want to access the form data inside your handleSubmit event? so, for example

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    emailMessageText: emailMessage,
  });

const handleSubmit = (initialValues, {e, setSubmitting }) => {
    //here in the below messageText I can only access the original value of the 
    //emailMessageText. i.e. can't get what user had updated post form rendered

    let req = {
      campusID: campusID,
      messageText: initialValues.emailMessageText
    };

}
<Formik
                enableReinitialize
                initialValues={formValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              >
                {({
                  submitForm,
                  handleBlur,
                  isSubmitting,
                  isValid,
                  touched,
                  values,
                  errors,
                }) => (
                  <Form>
                    <div>
                      <Grid
                        container
                        direction="row"
                        justify="center"
                        alignItems="center"
                      >
                        <Grid item lg={3} md={5} xs={12}>
                          <FormControl fullWidth>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="primaryCampusID">
                              Campus
                            </InputLabel>

                            <Field
                              component={Select}
                              type="text"
                              name="primaryCampusID"
                              validate={handleCampusSelection}
                              inputProps={{
                                id: "primaryCampusID",
                              }}
                              value={campusID}
                            >
                              <MenuItem value={0} key={0}>
                                Select Campus...
                              </MenuItem>

                              {campuses.map((option) => (
                                <MenuItem
                                  value={option.value}
                                  key={option.value}
                                >
                                  {option.key}
                                </MenuItem>
                              ))}
                            </Field>
                            <FormHelperText error>
                              <ErrorMessage name="primaryCampusID" />
                            </FormHelperText>
                          </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                          container
                          item
                          lg={12}
                          md={12}
                          xs={12}
                          spacing={5}
                          justify="space-between"
                          className={classes.rowSpacing}
                        >
                          <Grid item lg={12} md={12} xs={12}>
                            <FormControl fullWidth>
                              <Field
                                component={TextField}
                                multiline
                                fullWidth={true}
                                //label="Email Message"
                                validate={validateData}
                                placeholder="Email Message"
                                name="emailMessageText"
                                rows="15"
                              ></Field>

                              <FormHelperText error>
                                <ErrorMessage name="emailMessageText" />
                              </FormHelperText>
                            </FormControl>
                          </Grid>
                          <Grid item lg={12} md={12} xs={12}>
                            <Button
                              variant="contained"
                              color="primary"
                              size="medium"
                              className={classes.buttonGreen}
                              startIcon={<EmailIcon />}
                              disabled={!isFormDataValid}
                              
                              onClick={() => {
                                setConfirmOpen(true);
                              }}
                            >
                              Email
                            </Button>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                    </div>
                  </Form>
                )}
              </Formik>

<ConfirmDialog
              title="Send Notification emails?"
              open={confirmOpen}
              setOpen={setConfirmOpen}
              onConfirm={handleSubmit}
            >
              <Typography style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>
                {"This job will send notice emails to " +
                  currentPermitHolders.length +
                  " members." +
                  ".\n\n" +
                  " This is a non reversible action. Do you still want to Proceed with the submission?"}
              </Typography>
            </ConfirmDialog>
```

Comment: try to put `ConfirmDialog` inside Formik `Form` tag

Comment: Thanks @Usama though it didn't work.

Comment: Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002434/13405106). Instead of `submitForm` use `handleSubmit` as you are using handleSubmit in `onSubmit`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006718/what-is-the-difference-betwee-submitform-handlesubmit-onsubmit-in-formik?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Usama none of these worked so, I have taken a crude approach for now which I didn't like but it works. So, for now I've created another state variable like below let [emailMessage, setEmailMessage] = useState('') and I set the state of this variable if the email text is a valid text i.e. I've a few checks to ensure that user enters certain dynamic values in the pre-filled email message. Not an ideal solution but works for now. I'll revisit this later. Thanks for your tips. Much appreciated.